# Setting minimum line spacing in collectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to set the minimum line spacing using swift in my collectionViewController, but i can't seem too find the method i need to use. I need this to be programmatically since i need to change this dynamically depending on the selectedSegmentedIndex. How can i change the minimum line spacing programmatically?

i've tried to add the UICollectionViewFlowLayout, but cant since it's a UICollectionViewController.

i guess i need to use something like.

```
collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Make your `UICollectionViewController` conform to the protocol `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

The method you're looking for is:

`- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section;`

Comment: i need to change minimum space "for lines".

Comment: Yes - this method should do that.

Answer (score 9):

Swift:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
    collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2**

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 10
    }
```